# Docker run appears to ignore the name argument

Tags: docker

I've built a docker image based on some Dockerfile that I have written.

`docker build -t someuser/somerepo:sometag .`

But when I run this image with a name attribute it's apparently ignored.

`docker run -t someuser/somerepo:sometag -d --name="somename"`

Docker ps then gives;

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                  NAMES
a0225d20fddf        someuser/somerepo:sometag   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/lo   26 seconds ago      Up 26 seconds       8600/tcp, 8600/udp   tender_curie`

Where the name assigned follows dockers random name generator.

The image itself is working as intended and seems to be doing its thing.  This is seemingly trivial, I know, but I just can't make the running container accept a name.  I've tried as many variations of "--", in/excluding the equal sign, different quote characters etc as I can think of.

So the question is; what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look at the syntax of the run command: http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

`[options]` go before `IMAGE`

so you should try

```
docker run -t -d --name="somename" someuser/somerepo:sometag
```